# Create xml from attributes in a text file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, attributes

`I am doing in C#. I have certain elements and attributes. In addition to this certain attributes I need to create dynamically at run time. These attributes are kept in a text file. At run time these attributes have to be picked up and based on all these attributes xml should be generated. Currently I am getting xml as :

```
 <btm>
 <test testin="abc" isform="true" address="0" compressionType="9">
 <advancedSettings>
 <AdvancedSettings name=" TimeIntervalMin"/>
 <AdvancedSettings name=" GroupID"/>
 <AdvancedSettings name=" Blabla2"/>
 </advancedSettings>
 </test>
 </btm>
```

Ideally I want

```
 <btm>
 <test testin="abc" address="0" Type="9" TimeIntervalMin=""          GroupID="" Blabla2="" >
 </test>
 </btm>`
```

Those shown in advanaced settings are got from text file. How to do this.

My code:

```
 public class AdvancedSettings
 {
      [XmlAttribute]
      public string name { get; set; }
      public string value { get; set; }

 }
 [XmlRoot]
 public class btm
 {
     [XmlElement("test")]
     public List<info>information;
 }
 public class info : ISerializable
 {
    public info() { }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Address { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int comType { get; set; }

    public List<AdvancedSettings> advancedSettings = new List<AdvancedSettings>();
}
```

This is wrong I know. BUt I dont know how to correct it.Please help.

```
<btm>
<test testin="abc" Address="0" compressionType="9">
<advancedSettings>
<AdvancedSettings name=" TimeIntervalMin"/>
<AdvancedSettings name=" GroupID"/>
<AdvancedSettings name=" Blabla2"/>
</advancedSettings>
</test>
</btm>
```

Thhis is what I got which is wrong. I want the text file elements as attributes not elements`

Comment: So what *do* you want? Please show

Comment: <BottomHoleAssembly>
 <Tool toolID="abc" IsMWDTool="true" slaveAddress="0" compressionType="9" TimeIntervalMin=""          GroupID="" Blabla2="" >
 </Tool>
 </BottomHoleAssembly>`

Comment: But these last three eelements are not known at compile time. IT comes from a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compose XML dynamically on the fly via *LINQ to XML*.

It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    // static part
    XElement xelem = new XElement("BottomAssembly",
        new XElement("Tool",
        new XAttribute("toolID", "abc"),
        new XAttribute("IsMWDTool", "true"),
        new XAttribute("slaveAddress", "0"),
        new XAttribute("compressionType", "9")
        )
    );
    Console.WriteLine(xelem);

    // add XML attributes dynamically as you wish, loop through *.txt file, etc.
    xelem.Element("Tool").Add(new XAttribute("TimeIntervalMin", "206"));
    xelem.Element("Tool").Add(new XAttribute("GroupID", "18"));
    Console.WriteLine(xelem);
}
```

**Output**

```
<BottomAssembly>
  <Tool toolID="abc" IsMWDTool="true" slaveAddress="0" compressionType="9" />
</BottomAssembly>

<BottomAssembly>
  <Tool toolID="abc" IsMWDTool="true" slaveAddress="0" compressionType="9" TimeIntervalMin="206" GroupID="18" />
</BottomAssembly>
```

Comment: Thank u for the answer. The dynamic part gives error :                                                   
            Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20.
My line of code : 
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                xelem.Element("Tool").Add(new XAttribute(arr[i], 0));
            }

Comment: What is the value in the `arr[i]`? Check it out *"XML Naming Rules"* section here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: There was a space in the front. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
 [XmlRoot("BottomHoleAssembly")]
 public class BottomAssembly
 {
     [XmlElement("Tool")]
     public lwdinformation toolInformation;
 }
 public class lwdinformation
 {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string toolID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool IsMWDTool { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int slaveAddress { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int compressionType { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public TimeIntervalMin { get ;set; }          
    [XmlAttribute]
    public GroupID { get ;set; } 
    [XmlAttribute]
    public Blabla2 { get ;set; }

}
```

Comment: but these elemenets  TimeIntervalMin GroupID blabla2  are coming from a text file. At compile time its not sure what elements are there in that text file. it has to be taken at runtime and populated as attributes

Comment: You must have the above classes to get the desired results.  You have to parse the text file and add the data to the classes.  What does the text file look like?

Comment: ToolAdvancedSettings: PumpsOffAcq, AllowSTM, Blabla                                                                                             
DatapointAdvanceSettings: TimeIntervalMin, GroupID, Blabla2

Comment: That doesn't help